# Sqlite databse puts data in the wrong columns

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having a problem with my database when I try to add data from the simulator it puts it in the wrong column. I understand that it begins from 0 like (1 column = 0, 2 column = 1....)

I think I set it to 1 to put the data in the 2 columns but instead it puts it in the 3 columns but when set it to "0" it adds data the first column like it supposed to. Anybody has any ideas why it might be happening?

```
package com.example.laivumusis;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewListData extends AppCompatActivity {

    KlausimynoDatabaseHelper myDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editlistview_layout);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
         myDB = new KlausimynoDatabaseHelper(this);

        ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();

        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewListData.this,"Database tuščias!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            while (data.moveToNext()){
                theList.add(data.getString(1));
                ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the index of the column like this:

```
theList.add(data.getString(1));
```

Use the method [`getColumnIndex()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)) by passing the name of the column, because the order of the columns may not be what you think it is.
So change to this:

```
theList.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("columnName")));
```

Replace `columnName` with the name of the column that you want.

Comment: Added like this but it still puts in the wrong Collumn and the the `COLUMN` is writen with a typo so the declaration is okey and i put the collumns in the diffrent forms so thats why wrote it like that
`theList.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION")));`

Comment: No, remove the double quotes because you use a variable and not a string literal: `theList.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION)));`

Comment: Nope didin't work ether the same problem still exists

 `theList.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(KlausimuContracts.KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION)));`

Comment: Then the problem is that the column COLUMN_QUESTION contains other data than what you think. Check your insert methods to find what you insert in the tabe.

Comment: Is `KlausimuContracts.KlausimuLentele` a typo?

Comment: No the (table names, collums) are in other form so its the only way i can get the collumn names from the form

Comment: The column names should be inside the `KlausimynoDatabaseHelper ` class in which you manage the database so that you could retrieve them like `mydB.COLUMN_QUESTION`.

Comment: Thx forpas for the help i found the problem in the databasehelper form that i tried to add option 1 to the database not the question, Props to you for helping and teaching me a new command :P